# Disable sliding animation which is not applied through code

Tags: android, animation, samsung-mobile, android-sliding

I am getting one strange issue. I have not applied any sliding animation while redirecting from 1 activity to another activity. But, I have checked my application in Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge[OS version 7.0], it is displaying sliding animation when redirected to another activity. I am not getting this why this is happening. any help appreciated.

Comment: It is happening because Samsung has its own custom ROM, It can also happen with MI, Oppo, Vivo etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your activity when you are using intent to jump to another activity

`overridePendingTransition(0, 0)`

Ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int)

Comment: is this mandatory to apply thing all the time while we open new activity? i do not want any animation while change activity.

Comment: Yes it will also help to enabling the animation when you want.